# AngularJS - All latest versions of IE are ignoring dynamic width data

Tags: angularjs, width

I am working on a web application and I am trying to display a progress bar that has dynamic widths (based on progress bar label) in Internet Explorer. I am working in versions of Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 IE. When loading the view in IE the width is being displayed as style="" instead of style="width:{{progressBar.percent}}%".

I am able to render the dynamic color and label of the progress bar in Internet Explorer. However, I am unable to render the width of the progress bar dynamically. If I hand-type in the width it works fine but the width is going to change daily so hand-typing in the width isn't a solution.

Please Note: I have tested the progress bar on many other browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera and they all render the data correctly.

Here is my code:

```
 <div ng-model="widget.progressBar" ng-repeat="progressBar in widget.progress" class="progress-bar-{{progressBar.color}}"style="width:{{progressBar.percent}}%">
  <div class="progress-bars">{{progressBar.label}}</div>
  <div class="progress-bars-text">{{progressBar.number}}</div>
  <div class="dash-progress-num">{{progressBar.number}}</div>
 </div>
```

The part that does not function is style="width:{{progressBar.percent}}%". I also tried ng-style and that ended up displaying style="width:25%" however it did not actually change the size progress bar and it broke the other web browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest using the ng-style directive. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Comment: Thank you that did display style="width:25%" in my debugging console but the width did not actually change and that broke the other browsers.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kw685pjz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more research and what ended up working for me was ng-attr-style="width:{{progressBar.percent + '%' }}".

I started learning about attr on this website...https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive